# $\int_{0}^{4a} f(x)\;dx=4\cdot \int_{0}^{a} f(x)\;dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R_+}$ be a integrable function. If for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$f(4a-x)=f(x),\; \forall \; x \in \mathbb{R}$$
then is true that
$$\int_{0}^{4a} f(x)\;dx=4\cdot \int_{0}^{a} f(x)\;dx?$$

I think it's true and I couldn't think of a counterexample.

I know that if $f(2a-x)=f(x)$ then $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2a} f(x)\;dx=2\cdot \int_{0}^{a} f(x)\;dx$ holds.

Comment: There is a counterexample.  Keep trying.

Comment: Take $f(x)=x$ and $a=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $$f(x)=\sin(x)$$ and$$a=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
then

$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\;\; \;\;f(4a-x)=f(x)$$

but

$$\int_0^{4a}f=\int_0^\pi\sin(x)dx=2$$
and
$$4\int_0^af=4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin(x)dx\ne 2$$

Answer (score 2):

Let's try: $a=\frac{\pi}{2}, f(x)=\cos(x)$.